# Атрибут :selected в select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Есть такой select:

```
<%= select_tag('group_by',
  options_for_select([[]] + @query.groupable_columns.collect {|c| [c.caption,  
    c.name.to_s]}, @query.group_by)) %>
```

Подскажите, как добавить в него атрибут `:selected`, чтобы по умолчанию в нем было пусто, т.е. `:selected => ""`?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте третьим параметром хелпера `select_tag` атрибут `include_blank: true`, в результате у вас автоматически добавится в начало пустая строка, которая будет выбрана по умолчанию

```
<%= select_tag('group_by',
  options_for_select(@query.groupable_columns.collect {|c| [c.caption,  
    c.name.to_s]}), include_blank: true) %>
```

Comment: не сработало, все равно по умолчанию ставится последние значение в этом списке. При том, пустое значение там есть по умолчанию, но на третьем месте: `<select name="group_by" id="group_by" selected="selected"><option value="cf_107">hidden</option><option value="cf_36">SMS</option><option value="">&nbsp;</option><option value="author">Автор</option><option selected="selected" value="cf_85">№ задачи у вендора</option></select>`

Comment: @S.Ivanov потому что у вас значение \@query.group_by не nil, т.е. уже имеется выбранное значение, как только оно примет значение nil будет выбрана первая строка. Я убрал в примере второй аргумент в хелпере options_for_select - попробуйте загрузить форму без него.

Comment: все-равно выставляет последнее значение в этом селекте:  `<option selected="selected" value="cf_85">№ задачи у вендора</option></select>`

Comment: @S.Ivanov откройте форму в новом окне, где нет POST и GET данных

Comment: так и делаю, в браузере ввожу: http://redmine-new/issues открывается страница, где этот селект выбран последним значением

Comment: заметил, что теперь в селекте 2 пустых значения

Comment: @S.Ivanov а вы [[]] + убрали?

Comment: убрал, выглядит так: `<%= select_tag('group_by',
                               options_for_select(
                                 @query.groupable_columns.collect {|c| [c.caption, c.name.to_s]}), include_blank: true
                       ) %>` но все равно по умолчанию последнее ставится

Comment: При том, что в `@query.group_by` лежит `nil`, по умолчанию все-равно что-то выбрано. Вот полная `@query`: `#<IssueQuery id: nil, project_id: nil, name: "_", filters: {"status_id"=>{:operator=>"o", :values=>[""]}, "watcher_id"=>{:operator=>"=", :values=>["me"]}}, user_id: 0, column_names: nil, sort_criteria: [["updated_on", "desc"]], group_by: nil, type: "IssueQuery", visibility: 0, options: {:totalable_names=>nil, :draw_relations=>nil, :draw_progress_line=>nil}>`